# Simple. How to right aligned a table?? What Am I missing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have search extensively and have not had any luck. I have try some of the right aligned coding and I appear to just make things worse. I try to research and fix the problem without asking question but here I am. Basically I need my table to right aligned. The table that has "invoice, date, total, payments, and balance remaining". I have attached a photo also. The code I have for just the table is below:

```
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Invoice</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              {{ job.job_number }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Date</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              {% if job.scheduled_on %}
                {{ job.scheduled_on | date: "%m/%d/%y" }}
              {% endif %}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Total</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              {{ job.total | currency }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Payments</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              {{ job.total_applied_payments | currency }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>Balance Remaining</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              {{ job.balance | currency }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div><!-- .col-xs-4 -->
  </div><!-- .row -->
```

[photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz8w6csdrbf2b7s/invoice1.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: You want the *table* right aligned? Or the *text within certain columns* right aligned? Or the *text within all columns* right aligned?

Comment: It looks like it already is right-aligned